# Trying to get row data onClick

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html-table, datatable, element-ui

I'm trying to get row data from this table when a row is clicked, specifically the ID. I'm able to do this already because I added the IDs to the rows and utilize `event` to get the row data that way. My issue is that if I click on one of the child (nested)rows, I need to know their IDs(already doing that with `event`) but I also need to know the ID of the parent row. So for example, if I click on the **Test 320** row, the child row ID is 320 but how can we also know the parent row ID (2014 Golf -->5)?

**How I'm getting the row IDs for the ones that get clicked:**

```
this.rowId = event.target.parentNode.childNodes[1].innerHTML;
```

[image]

```
      <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Filter by Model or Trim" class="filter" />
      <el-table :data="tableData" class="padded-table" height="600" style="width: 100%" row-key="id">
        <el-table-column prop="name" label="TRIM" min-width="200"> </el-table-column>
        <el-table-column prop="technical" label="TECHNICAL" min-width="80"> </el-table-column>
        <el-table-column prop="customer_delivery" label="CUSTOMER DELIVERY" min-width="120"> </el-table-column>
        <el-table-column prop="customer_acceptance" label="CUSTOMER ACCEPTANCE" min-width="120"> </el-table-column>
        <el-table-column prop="off_the_truck" label="OFF THE TRUCK" min-width="80"> </el-table-column>
        <el-table-column prop="vim" label="VIM" min-width="80"> </el-table-column>
      </el-table>
```

Comment: Show your HTML
normally `this.rowId = event.target.closest("whatever").querySelector("someSelector").textContent`

Comment: Are you sure you need getting data from html? There are more efficient ways in vue.js. Can you provide your code which renders table?

Comment: Yes I'll update the question

Comment: Edited: data type tableData is an array of objects which represent each row in the table. Each object in this array can have a children array which is an array of objects that represent the child rows

Comment: This is using element-ui

Answer (score 4, accepted):

el-table has a built-in [`row-click` event](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table#table-events). Just listen to row-click and do something with the returned item.

```
<template>
  <el-table
    :data="tableData"
    @row-click="handleRowClick" // this line
    class="padded-table" 
    height="600" 
    style="width: 100%" 
    row-key="id"
  >
  ...
  </el-table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  ...
  methods: {
    handleRowClick(row) {
      console.log(row);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```